# Can the bit of random site icon placement at SE Data Explorer be changed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, icons

Is there a reason that some icons of SE sites are not paired up neatly with their respective meta icon on [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), while the vast majority are? If not or if it is bypassable, I suggest the order be changed.

[image: Screenshot with free-hand circles]
(Please ignore the fact that Stack Apps was erroneously included in a free-hand circle -- there is no meta site for it.)

Most notably, it is entirely unclear for a user why meta.tex.sx comes way before tex.sx, which is at the very end.

Related question that doesn't quite answer this one, if I understand correctly: [What criterion is used to determine which Stack Exchange 2.0 sites are included in the data explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72571/what-criterion-is-used-to-determine-which-stack-exchange-2-0-sites-are-included-i)

Comment: The criterion for inclusion is whether the site has graduated or not.

Comment: I believe the issue is ordering, not inclusion @ChrisF.

Comment: @M. Tibbits - I was answering his related question. I now see I wasn't 100% clear on that.

Comment: @ChristF: The related question is a link to another question, not a question I'm asking. But thanks for the info nonetheless ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now complete: 
[image: done]

We order by the name of site, **but** we try to group meta with the main site.

Comment: AU's meta is before the main site in your screenshot and Security, Physics & Android's meta are missing.

Comment: yeah I need to fix a few tables there sorting it out

Comment: Alrighty, thanks. Also, AU seems to be present twice when I view the site (also in your screenshot), so might want to check that out too :)

Comment: @yoda fixed now ... cheers

Comment: Cool. One more suggestion: TeX is at the end of the first row and TeX Meta at the beginning of the next. Perhaps they could go in the same row?